# Changing UIView Frame Origin with Autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

I'm trying to adjust the origin.y value of a UIView's frame.  The problem that I'm running into is that the elements aren't moving with the frame with negative offsets.  When I give the origin.y a positive value, it works perfectly: the view drops down, leaving black above, and the elements shift down as well.  With a negative value, on the other hand, the view moves correctly, leaving black below, but the elements don't change position.  I feel like the problem might be with autolayout, and the elements remaining trapped by the top of the screen, not the top of the UIView.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: try this code in viewWillAppear function.

Comment: if you are using autolayouts i think you can change a view's frame. you can create `IBOutlets` to constraints and change its value.

Comment: @erkamKUCET It needs to be done programmatically, not just once on load.

Comment: @Lucho The frame is updating right.  I'm not having trouble changing the frame.  It's just that the contents of the frame aren't updating if it's a negative offset.

Comment: I'm having the same problem after the recent updates, although I'm using the same code that used to work a couple of months before. For some reason, if you use constraints to determine the vertical positions for your elements using the bottom border (bottom layout guide) instead of the top guide, everything works as it should (temporal solution).